# Use Jquery slider value for D3 element

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to access the value of a jQuery slider and use it to position some text.

```
if (typeof(text) !== 'undefined' && text != '') {
    console.log(sliderVal);
    var sliderVal = $("#slider").val()
    var t = elt.append('text').text(text)
        .attr('x', box[0]).attr('y', box[1] + 500)
         .attr('dominant-baseline', 'hanging')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "14px");
```

I cant' figure out how to get that value of the slider so I can access it to so this:

```
.attr('y', box[1] + sliderVal)
```

instead of:

```
.attr('x', box[0]).attr('y', box[1] + 500)
```

Here is my slider element:

```
<input id="slider" class="bb" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"></input>
```

and some jQuery:

```
       $('#slider').on('change', function(e){
       var sliderVal = $('#slider').val();
       console.log(sliderVal);
```

Comment: question needs more info: which slider are you using? in almost all cases you should be able to check which child number the '.active' class is presently attached to

Comment: I updated the question to provide more info

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it was thought you were talking about image sliders. Your change function works so I would suggest placing the 'if' statement code into your 'change' function.